# How to calculate large exponents by hand?

Tags: math-history

How to calculate large exponents by hand like they did in ancient times?
Is it something to do with [***Prosthaphaeresis***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosthaphaeresis)? for example calculate $2^{15}$.

Comment: Of course $2^{15}=32768$ is one of those number known *by heart* (which for me also include $3^{11}=177147$ and ${49\choose 6}=13983816$ for other reasons), though this is of course a consequence of the ubiquity of that number in computer programming.

Comment: What's about exponentiation by squaring?

Comment: @Hagen Okay, I'll bite:  why do you have $\binom{49}{6}$ memorized?

Comment: I added a link to the term Prosthaphaeresis (I had to look it up, myself), in case anyone would like an explanation. [origin of word: Greek, prosthesis:addition, aphaeresis:subtraction -both used in the algorithm]

Comment: I learned a new word today (one that I cannot pronounce).

Comment: @TrevorWilson *Sigh* - do people never nag you with questions about lottery probabilities (which is "6 out of 49" over here)?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Oh, I see!  Fortunately they do not (so far.)

Comment: Prosthaphaeresis was quite short-lived. There were good trig tables, and as we know cos and sin are close relatives of the exponential. So they were used for a few years to replace multiplication by addition. But pretty soon after the discovery of the method, log tables became available, and the method faded into oblivion. In principle one could use the method for exponentiation. I know of no evidence that it was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use logarithms perhaps?

$$\log_{10} 2^{15} = 15\log_{10} 2 \sim 15\cdot0.3 =4.5$$
So that:
$$2^{15} \sim 10^{4.5} = 10^4\sqrt{10} \sim3\cdot 10^4$$
Which is just 7% percent away, and can be done in your head as long as you remember that $\log_{10} 2 \sim 0.3$, which most engineers probably do.

Comment: I made same way but did an error when trying to compute $10^{15}$ first instead of first $15 \cdot 0,3 = 4,5$ and then $10^{15 \cdot 0,3} = 10^{4,5}$

Comment: logarithms is what I first thought of too, but actually, the algorithm referenced by the OP predates the use of logarithms, historically, and the questions seems to pertain to more ancient history than that of the use of logarithms (see linked term in the post.)

Comment: @amWhy - the algorithm in the OP's post is merely 10's of years older than logarithms, neither of which I would describe as ancient.

Comment: My point is that neither was used in ancient times!